# Change the shape of multicolumn dataframe to multiindex

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a 1020x19478 size of dataframe. I would like to change 'r1', r2', and 'r3' as an index instead of columns. So it will change from multicolumn to multiindex. It is small sample of my dataset. I created it with this code.

```
sample1 = MC_opp12_v2.iloc[:3,5:8]
sample2 = MC_opp12_v2.iloc[:3,237:240]
sample3 = MC_opp12_v2.iloc[:3,469:472]
sample_df = pd.concat([sample1, sample2, sample3], axis=1)
print(sample_df)

         r1                r2             r3             
         p6      p7   p8   p6   p7   p8   p6   p7      p8
    b1  0.0  1.6896  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.7292
    b2  0.0  1.6896  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.7292
    b3  0.0  1.6896  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.7292
```

I should alter the r1, r2 and r3 columns into indexes after b1 b2 b3. I wrote this code. It is basic and suitable for small dataframes, but original one has 1020 b, 84 r and 232 p. And also r1, r2 and r3 is disappears in this code. How can I do this in my big dataframe?

```
b1r1 = sample_df.loc['b1', 'r1']
b1r2 = sample_df.loc['b1', 'r2']
b1r3 = sample_df.loc['b1', 'r3']
b2r1 = sample_df.loc['b2', 'r1']
b2r2 = sample_df.loc['b2', 'r2']
b2r3 = sample_df.loc['b2', 'r3']
b3r1 = sample_df.loc['b3', 'r1']
b3r2 = sample_df.loc['b3', 'r2']
b3r3 = sample_df.loc['b3', 'r3']

sample_final = pd.concat([b1r1, b1r2, b1r3, b2r1, b2r2, b2r3, b3r1, b3r2, b3r3])

new_index = ['r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r1', 'r2', 'r3', 'r1', 'r2', 'r3']
print(sample_final)

    p6      p7      p8
b1 0.0  1.6896  0.0000
b1 0.0  0.0000  0.0000
b1 0.0  0.0000  1.7292
b2 0.0  1.6896  0.0000
b2 0.0  0.0000  0.0000
b2 0.0  0.0000  1.7292
b3 0.0  1.6896  0.0000
b3 0.0  0.0000  0.0000
b3 0.0  0.0000  1.7292
```

Comment: `sample_df.stack(level=0)` would do.

Comment: It didnt change anything in my sample

Comment: I mean `sample_final = sample_df.stack(level=0)`. If that doesn't do, you should add `print(sample_df.to_dict())` to the question.

Comment: Can i ask you another question? The index names and column names are not sorted after stack(). How can i sorted them again

Comment: read on `sort_index`